# How to get a list of subdirectories from a file and then create those subdirectories in a directory?

Tags: bash

When a user inputs a name, there should be a new directory that gets created under that name.
In addition to that, the script needs to consult a file `structure1.txt` which is found in `/etc/scriptbuilder/str1`.
In this file, it will list two subdirectories (one on each line), the script is then supposed to create these two subdirectories in the new directory the user just made and named.

So how can the script then create each of the subdirectories that are listed in this text file?
I'm completely lost on that part.

This is my code so far:

```
 echo "Enter the project name "
 read name
 echo $name

 if [ ! -d $name ] then
 mkdir $name

 else 
 echo "The project name you entered already exists"
 fi

 cp /etc/scriptbuilder/str1/structure1.txt /$name 
 #I know this is wrong 
 because this would just copy the file over to the new directory but not actually 
 make the two subdirectories that are on the file onto the new directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bash command that you are looking for is `read`.
Also the syntax for your `if [ ! -d "$name" ]` should have a semicolon.
The else would typically have an `exit 1` (or some such value).
Typical bash code gets input from the command line, but what you want is fine.

For testing purposes, I inserted a `~` (tilde), which references your home directory.

The script should look something like:

```
filename="/etc/scriptbuilder/str1"
read -p "Enter the project name " name
echo "$name"
if [ ! -d ~/"$name" ]; then
  mkdir ~/"$name"
else 
  echo "The project name you entered already exists"
  exit 1
fi
while read -r line; do
  mkdir ~/"$name/$line"
done < "$filename"
```

You can clean up the formatting.

Comment: All this just to reimplement `xargs -a /etc/scriptbuilder/str1 -i mkdir -p {}`